# Python : How to add row dynamic

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to python/Kivy.

I have two files test.py and test.ky.
Now I am using two static row with serial number 1 and 2.
Can anyone tell me?
How to add row dynamic when click on '+add more' button.Now 2 row shows which are static row with serial number increment. 
I want add row dynamic 1 to 10 with serial number increment.

## test.py

```
import kivy

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (450, 525)

class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        print('test')

class test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "SN"
                valign: 'bottom'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .8
                text: "Value"
                valign: 'bottom'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 0, 5

            Button:
                text: '1'
                size_hint_x: .2

            TextInput:
                size_hint_x: .8

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 0, 5

            Button:
                text: '2'
                size_hint_x: .2

            TextInput:
                size_hint_x: .8

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 0
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .7
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom class for `Row` and `Rows`, then have a method adding rows.
I modified your example a bit. Try this:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.size = (450, 525)


class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.root



KV = """

<Row>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 0, 5

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: .8


display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "SN"
                valign: 'bottom'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .8
                text: "Value"
                valign: 'bottom'


        Rows:
            id: rows

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 0
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .7
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()

"""


test().run()
```